# PCA using rows as variables instead of columns

Tags: r, pca, vegan

I'm experiencing an awkward issue while trying to run a principal component analysis on my data. I've tried to use`prcomp`(base) and `rda`(vegan), but the analysis is considering columns as sample units instead of rows, which causes all sorts of issues with the analysis.

The following code is a simplification of my data. The actual dataset is composed of nearly 2000 columns and around 350 rows. However, the issue is the same when I run the script bellow:

```
rn <- rnorm(8000)
dt <- matrix(rn, nrow=80, ncol=1000)

result <- rda(dt, scale=T)
summary(result)
```

At first I thought this would be an common error, however I coudn't find any similar issues nor solutions to it.

Is there a way to clearly specify which dimension to use as sample units?

Comment: You can use `t()` to transpose your data into the format these functions expect.

Comment: MrFlick is right. In R the convention is always to put variables in columns and observations in rows. This makes it easy for users because we know that most functions work the same way. No need to guess what that particular author preferred.

Comment: I got the point. But the data is in the right format (i.e. rows as observations and columns as variables). Somehow R is cohercing the matrix the other way around, which is causing the analysis to be nonsense

Comment: @PedroRocha are you sure that you can perform PCA when you have more variables than observations?. I'm not sure but when running your example with the function`princomp` I got the error `Error in princomp.default(dt) : 
  'princomp' can only be used with more units than variables` which made me question whether it is possible and if not i think `rda` and `prcomp` might be transposing your data to perform the analysis.

Comment: Well, statistically speaking it's perfectly acceptable to perform PCA when you have more variables than observation. But you might be on to something regarding the implementation of PCA here

Comment: I am sure that R is not "cohercing the matrix the other way round", but it treats columns as variables. Probably you just misinterpreted the results.

Comment: @alejandroandrade `prcomp` and `rda` do **not** transpose data, but they use algorithm that can handle rank-deficit data (i.e., have more variables than observations). Function `princomp` uses different algorithms, and its author decided not to circumvent the issue (which could be done if wished).

Comment: @JariOksanen thanks for the clarification

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Whilst you can perform PCA on a data set with more variables, *p*, than observations, *n*, using the SVD method, there are at most *n* principal components, or *n*-1 if the data are centred.

If you dig into the results from the PCA you fitted, you'll see that it considered all variables and that they remained as variables:

```
> r2 <- rda(dt, scale=T)
> dim(scores(r2, display = 'species'))
[1] 1000    2
```

`'species'` is **vegan**'s way of referring to the variable loadings; there are 1000 variables.

Compare with `prcomp()`, which also used SVD:

```
> r1 <- prcomp(dt, scale = TRUE)
> dim(scores(r1, display = 'species'))
[1] 1000   80
```

again 1000 variables, 80 principal components (the reason for 80 here, vs 2 earlier is just the default for `choices`, i.e. which axes to extract scores for.)

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Given this is the first time I'm dealing with a dataset of this magnitude, I was misinterpreting the results. Your response made it clear! 
Cheers!